# aggregating profile feeds like facebook

Tags: facebook, nosql, redis

just wondering how you guys would do a feed aggregator like a simple facebook using nosql (like redis).

Basically you have many profiles, and each profiles would have their own feed. Everytime a user requests for an aggregate, the system would just fetch all these profiles, process them (and group them) and then displays to users. Problem with this approach is when someone has like 1000 friends, the system would have to fetch 1000 feeds (regardless if there's any update or not) and then process them.

How would you guys do it?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you can't do the updates in real time, you need to have done the update before the user asked for it - Basically you have a list of all known feeds and check for updates on a regular schedule, possibly based on the update frequency of each feed. When a user requests an aggregate you just need to return the data you already have.

Making sure that data is reasonably up to date is a bit trickier. If you are google you can check the entire internet every few minutes - not an option for most people. However, you can get reasonably close to real time with a combination of smart update scheduling and using real time apis where they are available. For something similar I am working on the basic architecture is a data store holding all posts and a number of processes that can pull data from a particular type of feed and add the posts to the data store in a common format.